# repeat loop has zero replacements

Tags: r, loops, repeat

I am trying to write a loop that compares the 'middle' value from the groups DT/DF to its preceeding columns. When the loop comes across a column that has a value larger than corresponding 'middle' column value, print that column name to a vector called mIncome and skip the remaining columns and go on to the next iteration in the loop. However, the loop doesn't seem to end.

I ultimately want a vector containing the name of the first column whose value is greater than the 'middle' value of the corresponding row.  I know loops aren't recommended, but if anyone has any suggestions...

```
groups <- dput(groups)
structure(list(one = c(33, 32, 161, 93, 69, 74, 24, 24, 21, 25
), two = c(53, 68, 164, 111, 96, 125, 35, 103, 39, 25), three = c(109, 
97, 188, 159, 160, 169, 53, 149, 106, 34), four = c(114, 161, 
214, 183, 302, 190, 86, 193, 155, 62), five = c(120, 183, 237, 
241, 384, 257, 105, 388, 174, 62), six = c(169, 269, 264, 262, 
633, 293, 195, 489, 239, 122), seven = c(209, 351, 351, 279, 
717, 326, 243, 652, 291, 152), eight = c(214, 393, 357, 346, 
769, 336, 255, 672, 353, 197), nine = c(238, 459, 365, 364, 816, 
336, 336, 722, 363, 197), middle = c(119, 230, 182, 182, 408, 
168, 168, 361, 182, 98)), .Names = c("one", "two", "three", "four", 
"five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "middle"), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000000000b0788>)




repeat{
   mIncome <- character(length = nrow(groups))

for(i in 1:(dim(groups)[1])){
   for(j in 1:(dim(groups)[2] - 1)){
      if(groups[i][[10]] < groups[i][[j]]){ # is middle value greater than...
         mIncome[i] <- as.character(colnames(groups[, j - 1, with = FALSE]))
         break
         } else (print('no')) 
      } 
    }
   mIncome
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues. One, in the text you say

> When the loop comes across a column that has a value larger than
>   corresponding 'middle' column value

but in your code, you have

`if(groups[i][[10]] > groups[i][[j]]){ # is middle value greater than...`

So, do you want where the value is greater than middle, or where middle is greater than value?

Second, when you find yourself using multiple nested `for` loops, there is probably an easier method.

I'm going to do this by first making a function, and then applying it to each row.

```
appfunc <- function(x) {
  if (!any(x[1:(length(x)-1)] > x[length(x)])) return("no")
  names(groups)[which(x[1:(length(x)-1)] > x[length(x)])[1]]
}
```

Let's unpack that. The function will be passed a row `x` from a `data.frame`, in this case I've assumed the `groups` `data.frame`. For the first row in your dataset, x would be `c(33, 55, 109, 114, 120, 169, 209, 214, 238, 119)`. The first line in the function is checking to see if any values of x other than the last element are greater than the last element, and if not return "no". If there is at least one value greater, the second line will return the first one, and return the corresponding name of that column.

So, for the first row in `groups`, we would expect the function to return "five".

Now, lets `apply` the function to each row of the `groups`.

`apply(groups, 1, appfunc)`

The syntax here is pretty simple. This is just saying to apply the `appfunc` we defined above to each row in `groups`.

Output:

```
# [1] "five"  "six"   "three" "four"  "six"   "three" "six"   "five"  "six"   "six"
```

Answer (score 1):

I just added `medclass[,j,with=FALSE]` and that should solve your problem. Here's a solution

```
for(i in 1:(dim(medclass)[1])){
  for(j in 1:(dim(medclass)[2] - 1)){
    if(groups[i][[10]] > groups[i][[j]]){ # is middle value greater than...
      mIncome[i] <- as.character(colnames(medclass[, j,with=FALSE]))
      next
    } else (print('no')) 
  }
}
```

Solution with correct indices:

```
for(i in 1:(dim(medclass)[1])){
  for(j in 1:(dim(medclass)[2] - 3)){
    if(groups[i][[10]] > groups[i][[j]]){ # is middle value greater than...
      mIncome[i] <- as.character(colnames(medclass[, j+4,with=FALSE]))
      next
    } else (print('no')) 
  }
}
```

By no means this is an efficient solution. An efficient solution must be out there.

Comment: I get a different error:  Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : subscript out of bounds.  Do I have to print anything? Can I skip the else statement and just have the true condition(middle > other column) print for each row?